# bootstrap conformation model is not open after 2nd time in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have to remove the image from the list in the conformation model click on the YES button but after 2nd time model is not open.In the element section after 2nd time click "

```html
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#openImage"></span>
<div id="openImage" class="modal in">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure???</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Are you sure you want to delete this product?</p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12-xs text-center">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" ng-click="removeSelectedProductKey($event, productObject.keyId)"> Yes</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-md"  data-dismiss="close">No</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

display :none" is apply tell me sir how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Your code is not enough, please make a fiddle or share some more code!

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your modal by function using:

```
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"  ng-click="openImg()"></span>
```

And inside your controller write below function:

```
function openImg(){
    angular.element('#openImage').modal();
}
```